# Looking for a particular book, and all I remember is the cover

Tags: story-identification, books, cover-art

I first read this book around 1983-1985 (no actual idea of when it was first printed), and, while I can't remember all that much from the book itself (other than enjoyable), I do remember the *cover* of the book.  The cover prominently featured and depicted a robot, silver in color, sitting down (maybe in a field of some sort?), drinking a cup of tea in a very posh 'pinky extended' fashion.

I've brought this fact up to friends, who have also read the book (and who are also trying to remember the book), and they always come back with 'Douglas Adam's: The Long Dark Teatime of the Soul.'  I am pretty sure this is not correct, for a quick GIS of that book, shows no covers bearing what I remember.

A small, small part of me, thinks it was a Heinlein book, but, none of the covers look familiar, I imagine it's possible the changed cover on a re-print, but, none of the titles stick out to me either.

Any help, and all the internets to you, if you find this book!

Comment: Long Dark Teatime of the Soul makes no sense. The only robot was an android, basically indistinguishable from a human.

Comment: @Richard That was the monk in _Dirk Gently_. There's no robot in _Teatime_.

Comment: Oops. Getting my books mixed up. Teatime was the one with the Act of God (but which God, and why?) :-)

Comment: Oh dear, so long ago. Ehm, a new and powerful Guilt God?

Comment: Actually, the god hanging around Heathrow waiting for the flight to Oslo was Thor, God of Thunder. Quite why he didn't take a boat or simply swim there is beyond me.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/27zzB.jpg) is another book cover by Bob Norrington of a robot drinking out of a dainty floral tea cup.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[*Special Deliverance*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1198133.Special_Deliverance) by Clifford Simak?

Answer (score 27):

It sounds like the book you're after is [Special Deliverance](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1198133.Special_Deliverance) by Clifford D. Simak, originally published in 1982.

[image: Special Deliverance]

The cover art was by [**Michael Whelan**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1804)

Comment: Richard, you have done this fellow human being a grand service.  Thank you, so, so much.  If I could upvote this answer a thousand times, I would.

Comment: One is glad to be of service

Comment: @Jasoomian if this answer nailed it, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Richard, was yours an 'original' answer, or just an expansion of mine?

Comment: I pinched your answer but the revision was so substantial that I couldn't justify doing an edit.

Comment: @Jasoomian - or you could credit ImaginaryEvents who actually found the answer.

Comment: @iandotkelly -  I feel that some people are downvoting because I posted a *more detailed answer* rather than vandalising ImaginaryEvents's stub answer

Comment: @Richard - personally I think identification questions are a special (and less interesting) case of general questions on sites like this, where the better answer is the first correct one, not necessarily the most detailed.  There are of course edge cases to this - but the work is done in identifying the novel/story etc.  You are correct in the more general question sense that detail, references etc are good things to add. I doubt people are downvoting "because its more detailed" - that in itself is a good thing.

Comment: @Richard - so I was just bringing it to the OPs attention that perhaps he should consider that when making a decision.  I appreciate the work you've done, but personally if it were my decision, I would chose the other answer (in this case)

Comment: @iandotkelly I'm not overly concerned about the "tick" for approval but I do think it's worth pointing out that the inclusion of a picture (and any info about the cover artist) is almost obligatory when answering a question *about* a book cover. Merely providing a link isn't enough imho

Comment: The error there, may be mine, I was so excited to see the cover art, that I may have missed ImagaryEvents answer.  Either answer is correct, I thanked Richard only because I did not see ImaginaryEvent's response first - sorry about that.

Comment: @Jasoomian The choice over "best answer" is completely down to you. You can reward speed or details or any other criteria you want. I'm just glad you found your book :-)

Comment: As am I - I found several copies on Amazon, and, one should be in my mailbox when I get home.  Thanks to all who chimed in.